# Get all latitude by type of place

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I want to save the latitude and longitude of all school(type: school) that mark in google map.
How can I do this?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can use google places api for android. see [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/intro) to configure on your project .